# Javascript Adding a dollar sign $ to my answer

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a $ to my final answer right now it currently returns the answer in a alert message as 500.00 depending o

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Simple Adder</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function CalculateSum(Atext, Btext)
{
var A = parseFloat(Atext);
var B= A * .03+.30+A;
alert(B.toFixed(2));
}
function ClearForm(form)
{
form.input_A.value = "";
form.Answer.value = "";
}

// end of JavaScript functions -->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<P><FONT SIZE="+2">Credit Card Payment Calculator</FONT></P>

<FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">
<P>Enter Base Rent: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_A" SIZE=10></P>
<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate Rent & Fees Payment" name="AddButton"    onClick="CalculateSum(this.form.input_A.value, this.form)"></P>
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alert('$' + B.toFixed(2));
```

The "toFixed()" function returns a string, so you just prepend your "$" to that.

It's a little hard to tell what you're asking for becau

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm. =) And sorry about it cutting off my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
alert('$' + B.toFixed(2));
```

Should work